# how can I debug theme.theme file in my theme using phpstorm?

Tags: theming, debugging

I want to set breakpoints in the `theme.theme` file and debug some variables but I cannot do that as this file isn't a `php` file. How can I debug this file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to Preferences -> Editor -> File Types
2. Scroll down the *Recognized File Types* list until you find PHP; select it
3. In *Registered Patterns* add *.theme
4. Save

You can now set breakpoints in *.theme files.

Comment: Nope - you can set breakpoints, but PHPStorm stops at the function declaration with the code containing the breakpoint - but then blows right through it. 

Step 1: added var_dump() to verify that the code was getting hit (it is)
Step 2: On a whim, put the breakpoint on the var_dump(). Viola - that breakpoint was hit (as well as any breakpoints beyond that. 

Strange solution and really more of a workaround that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure you are on the correct theme to trigger debugger.

A common mistake you could be doing:

Lets say you want to debug a hook_form_alter that is in the YOUR_THEME.theme file, you did everything, but it doesn't break. What could be wrong? Make sure when you are visiting your form, you are using the YOUR_THEME theme and not the administration theme which will load by default if you are an administrator and you may end up confused why debugger doesn't stop at your break line.

Answer (score 0):

For me disabling cache helped as my preprocess mytheme_preprocess_paragraph() function was not triggered because of cache.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you may want full drupal integration with phpstorm. [Here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Drupal+Development+using+PhpStorm) you can read how to achieve this.